# Undefined index and undefined offset for form

Tags: php, sql, indexing, offset

I'm a new student in development and for myself I created a website where I can put my results when I did some sport (bicycle for example), but I have many problems in there.
The first one: Undefined index on lines 34 and 35
The second one: Undefined offset of every input of my form

You can check my code here:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //Connexion
    include('connexionBDD.php');
    //Form
    if(isset($_POST['enregistrement'])) {

        if($_POST['seance'] == 'new') {
            //REQ (INSERT)
            $req = "INSERT INTO `donnees_velo` (`SEANCE`, `DATE`, `CALORIES`, `DUREE`,`DISTANCE`,`PUISSANCE`, `CALORIES PAR HEURE`,`MOVEs`,`FCMOY`,`FCMAX`,`PERFORMANCE`,`VITESSE`) 
                    VALUES (NULL, '".$_POST['date']."','".$_POST['calories']."', '".$_POST['duree']."', '".$_POST['distance']."','".$_POST['puissance']."', '".$_POST['calories_heure']."', '".$_POST['MOVEs']."','".$_POST['FCMOY']."', '".$_POST['FCMAX']."', '".$_POST['PERFORMANCE']."','".$_POST['VITESSE']."');";
                    echo $req;
        } else {
            echo $req = "UPDATE `donnees_velo` 
                    SET `DATE` = '".$_POST['date']."', 
                        `calories` = '".$_POST['calories']."'
                        `DUREE` = '".$_POST['duree']."'
                        `DISTANCE` = '".$_POST['distance']."'
                        `CALORIES PAR HEURE` = '".$_POST['calories_heure']."'
                        `MOVEs` = '".$_POST['MOVEs']."'
                        `FCMOY` = '".$_POST['FCMOY']."'
                        `FCMAX` = '".$_POST['FCMAX']."'
                        `PERFORMANCE` = '".$_POST['PERFORMANCE']."'
                        `VITESSE` = '".$_POST['VITESSE']."'
                        WHERE `seance` = '".$_POST['idvelo']."'";
                        echo $req;
        }

        //EXE REQ (QUERY)
        $db->query($req);
        header('Location: index.html');
        exit();
    }
    if($_GET['seance'] != 'new') {
        $req = "SELECT * FROM `donnees_velo` WHERE `seance` = '".$_GET['id']."'";

        //REQ LAUNCHING
        $rep = $db->query($req);

        //REQ TO TBL
        $tbl_velo = $rep->fetchAll();
    } else {
        $tbl_velo[0]['id'] = 'new';
        $tbl_velo[0]['date'] = '';
        $tbl_velo[0]['calories'] = '';
        $tbl_velo[0]['duree'] = '';
        $tbl_velo[0]['distance'] = '';
        $tbl_velo[0]['calories_heure'] = '';
        $tbl_velo[0]['MOVEs'] = '';
        $tbl_velo[0]['FCMOY'] = '';
        $tbl_velo[0]['FCMAX'] = '';
        $tbl_velo[0]['PERFORMANCE'] = '';
        $tbl_velo[0]['VITESSE'] = '';
    }
    var_dump($tbl_velo);
?>


<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pagedeux.css">
<title>Vélo</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="overlay"></div>
    <p class="line-1 anim-typewriter">Le vélo</p>
    <form action="velo.php" method="POST" >
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $tbl_velo[0]['SEANCE']; ?>" name="seance">
    Date : <input name="date" value="<?php echo $tbl_velo[0]['date']; ?>" type="date"><br/>
    Calories : <input name="calories" value="<?php echo $tbl_velo[0]['calories']; ?>" type='text'><br/>
    Durée : <input name="duree" value="<?php echo $tbl_velo[0]['duree']; ?>" type="text">
    Distance : <input name="distance" value="<?php echo $tbl_velo[0]['distance']; ?>" type="text">
    Calories par heure : <input name="calories_heure" value="<?php echo $tbl_velo[0]['calories_heure']; ?>" type="text">
    MOVEs : <input name="MOVEs" value="<?php echo $tbl_velo[0]['MOVEs']; ?>" type="text">
    Fréquence cardiaque moyenne : <input name="FCMOY" value="<?php echo $tbl_velo[0]['FCMOY']; ?>" type="text">
    Fréquence cardiaque mxaimale : <input name="FCMAX" value="<?php echo $tbl_velo[0]['FCMAX']; ?>" type="text">
    Performance : <input name="PERFORMANCE" value="<?php echo $tbl_velo[0]['PERFORMANCE']; ?>" type="text">
    Vitesse : <input name="VITESSE" value="<?php echo $tbl_velo[0]['VITESSE']; ?>" type="text">
  <input type="submit" name="enregistrement" value="Envoyer">
</form>
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Hey there! And welcome! You need to share a bit more of your understanding of these error messages so that answers (incl. existing ones) can be helpful to you. Please see the linked reference for general guidance on PHP errors for reference. And let me know what was helpful and what is still a burden to understand. Thanks (a lot)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching the `'seance'` and `'id'` from your `$_GET` variable, while the two of them are present in your `$_POST` variable due to being sent from a form.
You should replace the instances of `$_GET` by `$_POST` in these two places.
Furthermore, be careful about your `$_POST['id']` variable which is susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection), I'd recommend sanitizing it.

Comment: Not only `id`, but all the values should be passed via bind variables instead of concatenation. Apart from SQL injection it also improves performance.

Comment: Hello! thank you a lot for your help !

Comment: @Choupette Do not hesitate to mark the answer as accepted if it helped :)